# How can I access favorite/bookmarked questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I can't seem to find my "bookmarked" questions.

I was expecting a star icon somewhere in one of the menus that would show me a list of my favorite questions, but I can't find it.

Where are these questions located?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/where-did-my-bookmarked-questions-go

Answer (score 155, accepted):

#### Update (Feb 2023)

Bookmarks are moved under Saves. You can access it using this link [stackoverflow.com/users/saves/current](https://stackoverflow.com/users/saves/current/all)

#### Original Answer

Click on your profile image from any page (top right with reputation points and medals).

Then it will lead to your profile page or go to
https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/current.

Click on tab **Activity** (if not default) and click on **Bookmarks**.

Comment: do you think this is bad UX part as the main reason is question website and sure I will need back to questions I marked it took 3 minutes on profile page and until now not able to see bookmark or found word bookmark on all page while it must be in middle of the profile page as I see a lot of un needed things very clear

Comment: They're now hidden under Saves.  Took me a while to find them.

Comment: @KyleAlons's comments should be the selected answer

Answer (score 30):

I found it here under tab saves

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/saves/current/all

---

also to complete the answer as  recommend by @[kalinda-pride](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8340554/kalinda-pride) the all bookmarks may be temporarily missing from the Saves tab, that's because as mentioned in this answer by @[TheMaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/where-did-my-bookmarked-questions-go#answer-420681)

> The migration process will take some time to process as there are
> millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If you’re not seeing
> any questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been
> processed yet.

Comment: This is correct. But some of the bookmarked questions may be temporarily missing from the Saves tab: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/where-did-my-bookmarked-questions-go

Comment: yes I have read the answer you shared, and updated my answer to mention this important point thank you.

Comment: This is the correct answer for 2022

Comment: inconsistency in UI design.

Answer (score 22):

As well as using [your Bookmarks tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks), you can [search for `inbookmarks:mine`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inbookmarks%3Amine).

Note that the previous name for Bookmarks, Favorites, still works as an alias for all the above links/search parameters.

Comment: With this possibility, users and apps can use this site as a reference database of "the journey" that users experience on the Stack Overflow Network. There should be another "shortcut": inhistory:mine

Comment: "58,778,571 results" I don't think this works anymore

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to your [profile page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/current).
2. Look at the image below and everything should be clear.

   - From the image, option 3 is not required but if you want see your last added favorite question then that's the tab you should click.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Previously, Bookmarks was named Favorites. It was renamed to Bookmarks to have a better semantic resemblance of the function. You bookmark a post to receive notifications on its status. So just follow the same instructions, but look for Bookmarks instead of Favorites.

For the most recent changes to the site follow this link to: [recent feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/342029#342029)

Answer (score 5):

There is a **Favourite** tab on your profile use this to access all starred questions.

Answer (score 5):

For URL access, add `?tab=favorites` to the user page.

(And btw, it's a public link.)  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333742?tab=favorites