# Need a searchbox in bookmarks section

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, search, bookmarks

We can bookmark our favourite questions and later find them in "Activity > Bookmarks".

In the bookmarks section we can sort by various ways but a search option would make things easier.

Comment: [`inbookmarks:mine`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Related: [Does searching give any priority to my favorited questions/answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378785/215552), [How can I access favorite/bookmarked questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344661/215552), both of which mention the search filter.

Comment: @Zoe thanks for shading light on that. But I just forget things. I, hope that SO will add a search option there.

Comment: When you click the search bar, it says "search help" in the bottom-right corner. Clicking that shows you the page I linked. if you forget, you can always click the help button.

Comment: I've been on SO for less than 1year already have 132 bookmarks. Any plan to introduce bookmarks subcategories