# The ability to search or categorize Stack Overflow bookmarks

Tags: discussion

I do not know if this is the place to suggest this. I bookmark a lot of questions on the website for future reference. I feel that a lot of people most likely use this feature since bookmarking is available. I am also a part of different communities. Since I have a decent amount of bookmarks, it would be nice if there was a search option to search through the bookmarks or a way to categorize them. It would make using the bookmarks so much easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a searchbox in bookmarks section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401110/need-a-searchbox-in-bookmarks-section)

Comment: [Organizing Bookmarks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402054/11682469)

Comment: Oh, ask on Meta Stack Overflow if you have a feature request for the site.