# Where did my bookmarked questions go?

Tags: bug, bookmarks, saves

I had a bunch of questions bookmarked, but now I can't find them on my profile page. A quick Google search shows me results that are all from 2014 or prior. Where did they go?

Comment: I assume you have verified the questions were not deleted?

Comment: Seems like an update is being made as we discuss. There's a new tab called "saves", next to "activity". However, I can't find my previous bookmarks there.

Comment: Also, both https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites  and https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites both redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/users/saves/[your-id] now.

Comment: MSE answer: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-are-evolving-into-saves)

Comment: I'm 99% sure the old bookmarks were supposed to be preserved in the shift to saves though

Comment: What a terrible way to _rollout_ a new feature. Migrate the data **first**, then toggle the new UI 

Comment: @Phil agreed 110% and I wrote on the MSE post to complain about it.

Comment: Incredible that no one thought people would miss their bookmarks! Poor form StackOverflow!

Comment: Yes, this is unsettling. The bookmarks appear to be gone. The user interface ought to have some indication. E.g., instead of *"All saves"*, it could say *"All saves (existing bookmarks are in the process of being migrated and will not be available for a few days. See XXX meta post for details. For workarounds, see YYY.)"*

Comment: (*"All saves"* is the default view when opening the *"Saves"* tab/button, so it should be fairy well discoverable.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bookmarks are being turned into Saves. As written in the [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/),

> The migration process will take some time to process as there are millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. **If you’re not seeing any questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been processed yet.**

Give some time for the processing to complete.

---

Update Oct 5

Migration is paused temporarily and Bookmarks feature is turned back on. If your bookmarks are migrated(to saves), **they will NOT be available in bookmarks**. If they're not migrated, they will be available.

[MSE update says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/):

> Saves has been temporarily disabled network-wide due to some site performance problems.

> Stack Overflow was the only site partially migrated

> Around 360k bookmarks were turned into saves
> Around 14mil bookmarks are still bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

According to [the post TheMaster has linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves), I guess Bookmarks is being renamed Saves and is getting a bunch of new features such as creating a new lists (instead of a single bookmarks list) etc. The old bookmarks are meant be moved there but as [TheMaster mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420681/19123103) (and also written in the FAQ section of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)), it's going to take time.

> **What will happen to my existing bookmarks?**
>
> We will be migrating over your existing bookmarks into the default
> “For later” Saves list. Once we enable the Saves feature, the
> migration process will take some time to process as there are millions
> of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If you’re not seeing any
> questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been
> processed yet.

Currently, it looks like this but the bookmarks are meant to appear here.

[image: saves]